Running variable++ adds 2 instead of 1
I am trying to increment a value by 1. No matter what I try it always adds more than 1. I know the function only gets called once, and only when a button is clicked.
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

const handleSubmit = () => {
  setCounter(counter + 1)

  // TO SHOW ME HOW MANY TIMES THE FUNCTION RUNS.
  // ONLY INCREMENTS BY 1 EACH TIME I CLICK THE BUTTON
  console.log('handleSubmit is running', counter)

  setLeveledChar(prevChar => {
    let newChar = { ...prevChar }
    // INCRIMENTS BY 1
    newChar.char_level++

    // SELECTED CLASS IS DIFFERENT DEPENDING ON WETHER OR NOT
    // ISmULTICLASING IS TRUE.
    // EITHER THE SELECTED MULTICLASS OR LEVELEDcHAR.PRIMARY_CLASS
    // BY CLASS I MEAN LIKE A ROLE PLAYING CLASS BTW. NOT A PROGRAMMING CLASS
    const leveledClass = isMulticlassing
      ? newChar.multiclass.find(x => x.name === selectedClass.name)
      : newChar.primary_class
        
    // INCRIMENTS BY 2
    leveledClass++

    return newChar
  })
}

I tried leveledClass.level = leveledClass.level + 1 and leveledClass.level += 1 but they both add 2.

If you remove <React.StrictMode>, it continue to happen?

The handleSubmit is mutating the current state's value and this mutation is exposed/surfaced by the React.StrictMode component's double-invocation of certain lifecycle methods and hook callbacks, the useState state updater functions in this case. The first call updates the state as you are expecting but the second call is also mutating the state, so this is why you see values incrementing by twos instead of ones.
All React state updates necessarily should shallow copy all state, and nested state properties, that are being updated. This is typically achieved using functional state updates.
Example implementation:
const handleSubmit = () => {
  setCounter(counter => counter + 1);

  setLeveledChar(prevChar => {
    // shallow copy of current leveledChar state object reference
    const newChar = { ...prevChar };

    // non-mutative update
    newChar.char_level += 1;

    if (isMulticlassing) {
      // Shallow copy array with map function
      newChar.multiclass = newChar.multiclass.map(x => x.name === selectedClass.name
        ? { // <-- new object reference and shallow copy array element
          ...x,
          primary_class: x.primary_class + 1
        }
        : x
      );
    } else {
      // non-mutative update
      newChar.primary_class += 1;
    }

    return newChar;
  });
}

